# Prove that every symmetric matrix can be diagonalized using similarity transformation even if it has repeated eigenvalue

Tags: symmetric-groups, diagonalization, jordan-normal-form

Prove that every symmetric matrix can be diagonalized using similarity transformation even if it has repeated eigenvalue by showing that the Jordan form of a symmetric matrix has no Jordan block of order 2.

Comment: Is this a HW problem? Sounds like it. What have you done so far? How is the Jordan form $\mathbf M$ related to the original matrix $\mathbf A$?